# Optaplanner 7.12.0 Vehicle routing CVRP shadow variable not updated

Tags: optaplanner

With optaplanner 7.12.0 multithreaded solving got a few fixes for working with chained variables. For me multithreaded solving works well with version 7.9.0 for vehicle routing but when upgrading to 7.12.0 I get the following error:

```
The entity (Visit-25) has a variable (previousStandstill) with value (Visit-24) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextVisit) with a value (Visit-12) which is not null.
Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.
```

It only occurs when custom moves are present. These custom moves worked well with version 7.9.0 (also when using full assert). 
I can replay this problem with the example code found here:
https://github.com/ge0ffrey/optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment (just upgrade to optaplanner 7.12.0).

Has anyone else seen this problem has an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: It could a bug in the `rebase()` method of the custom move. Send in a support ticket at access.redhat.com (I recall your company has access there).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey. I will do so next week.